# How do you test a docker image local before pushing(on Docker For Mac)

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I have seen dgoss, but goss is not for mac, so how do you test you images is working as expected before pushing to remote repo?

Thanks

Comment: Beyond `docker run` the thing that just got built, what sort of tests did you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of test are you talking about? If the Docker image has an external interface (open ports) and not too many backend dependencies, you can start it locally and invoke the external interface from outside.

For running test code inside a local container, I'm using a second Dockerfile that builds FROM the image to be tested. That second Dockerfile adds the test code, then I run a container with the extended image. Test results can be exported by copying them to a locally mounted directory.

Technically, that doesn't test the original image to be pushed though. For example, if some package is missing in the original image, but you're adding it as a dependency of the test code, the test might succeed though the original image is broken.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good question and sorry for not making it more clear. It is actually the process of running the image and the run tests up against the running container, external(localhost/machine) to the container, and then stopping it again from a script. I will update my question and upvoted your answer.

Comment: I think I will go for something, kind of this

Comment: It's been a while. I got rid of the second Dockerfile. Instead, I'm using volume mounts to bring the test code into the container running the image to be tested. Saves several seconds on each test run.